# How to optimize this code that checks if numbers are part of a recursive series?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Write Python code to find if all the numbers in a given list of integers are part of the series defined by:
>
> ```
> f(0) = 0  
> f(1) = 1  
> f(n) = 9*f(n-1) - 7*f(n-2) for all n > 1
> ```

Here is my implementation. But the problem is if we give 100th term in the input list then calculating series (last+5) is time-consuming and hardcoded too. Another way is we pre-calculate 50 terms of the series the its not memory-efficient. Can you help we write an optimal and correct solution?

```
f = [0,1]
first, second = f
last = 5
#lst = [0,189347579845,0,4909,603,4909, 3990, 325277]   
#sample input 

length_of_input = int(input("Enter the length of input list: "))
for num in lst:
    x = int(input("Enter element"))
    lst.append(x)

def calc_values(last):
    global first, second
    for n in range(2 , last):
        element = (9 * second) - (7 * first)
        f.append(element)
        first, second = second, element

def is_part_of_series(lst):
    
    for value in lst:
        if value==first or value==second:
            continue
        elif value > f[-1]: 
            while value > f[-1]:
                calc_values( last+5 )
                
        if value in f:
            continue
        elif value not in f:
            return "Not Found"
    return "found"               
print(is_part_of_series(lst))
```

Comment: Given `f(n)` is dependent on only the previous two values, you could run a loop from 0 to some large number, keeping only the last three values in memory. On each iteration of the loop you can check if the latest value is in your list. This will eventually give you an answer if all numbers to check are part of the series, but could run infinitely if one isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to build the series fully. You can do it, effectively, as required

```
series = [0, 1]


def is_num_in_series(x):
    global series
    if x in series:
        return True
    if x < series[-1]:
        return False
    while True:
        f = 9 * series[-1] - 7 * series[-2]
        series.append(f)
        if f == x:
            return True
        if f > x:
            break
    return False


print(is_num_in_series(4909))
print(series)
print(is_num_in_series(4910))
print(series)
```

I print series after each invocation to demonstrate how it extends as required

Comment: Making `series` a global is still dubious, but a vast improvement over the OP's code.

Comment: It's demonstration code for someone who's obviously new to the language. Perhaps you could share your improved solution

Answer (score 0):

The sequence always grows, so you can sort the input list and iterate over it, at the same time advancing in the sequence when needed (similar to how you merge two sorted lists):

```
def generate_f():
    a = 0
    b = 1
    while True:
        yield a
        a, b = b, 9*b - 7*a

def find_elements(lst):
    f = generate_f()
    cur = next(f)
    for item in sorted(lst):
        while item > cur:
            cur = next(f)
        if item == cur:
            yield item
        
lst = [0, 189347579845, 4909, 603, 3990, 325277]
print(list(find_elements(lst)))  # [0, 603, 4909, 325277]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it, defining a custom list that initially contains 0 and 1, then extends automatically as you search for matches:

```
from collections import UserList


class Solution(UserList):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__([0, 1])

    def __contains__(self, x):
        if x in self.data:
            return True

        if x < self[-1]:
            return False

        while self[-1] < x:
            self.append(9 * self[-1] - 7 * self[-2])

        return self[-1] == x


solution = Solution()

while True:
    x = int(input("Enter element (0 to interrupt): "))
    if x == 0: break
    print(x in solution)
```

And the question was: "find if all the numbers in a given list of integers are part of the series", so the check would be:

```
def check(numbers: list):
    return all(number in solution for number in numbers)
```